# How to test google play validation with a remote server?

Tags: android

I am currently in early development stage for android in app purchase.

I used static product ID android.test.purchased.

The returned result is `inapp:com.getcharly.android.user:android.test.purchased` for purchaseToken after the purchase was made.

But when I send this to my server and I used a node module for validation, it tells me that it is malformed.

So how do i make a proper purchase? Is the only way to do a beta/alpha release??? That is a huge turn around time for server development.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do i make a proper purchase? Is the only way to do a beta/alpha
>   release?

As seen in [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html):

> To test in-app billing, you need to publish your app to an alpha or beta channel in Google Play. After you publish an app to an alpha or beta channel, it can take a few hours for the app to be available for testers.

You have to publish it in alpha or beta channel, and then download it from there as a tester. Thereafter you may perform test purchases.

**Note**: don't forget register tester's mails in the Google Play, otherwise they will be charged. They should clearly see "TEST" text in the Play service's dialog.

Comment: Oh well. And beta/alpha release has to be signed with a the prod certificate.. Which means that there is no way for local development to test proper purchases.. and my remote server has to handle some weird productId..